# select options not updating dynamically with angular 2 bindings

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, html-select

I am unable to get `select` options to update dynamically with `Angular2` bindings. How do you update the contents of the `select` dynamically?

[Plnkr explaining my issue.](https://plnkr.co/edit/1266K3RtP2K9xXyVQNjp?p=preview) Notice the `select` options never update to the new array i set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you are reassinging `options` value you have to point to `options` of current by using `this` before `options`.

```
handleChange(event) {
    console.log(event.target.value);
    //this to indicate options from current class
    this.options = [{id: 0, name:"First"}, {id: 1, name:"Second"}, {id: 2, name:"Third"}];

    this.selected1 = this.options.filter((option) => {
      return option.id == event.target.value;
    })[0];    
}
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/M9OtkCq31Z0brtWSJl3r?p=preview)

Comment: You are right that would solve this problem, my problem was a little more detailed than that and i thought this simple plunk would show the problem. It does not show the exact problem i was having. However, i did find the actual solution.

Comment: What was that then? Could you please tell me?

Comment: I needed to make a default selection on my second "select" before it would update the "select" options. Weird...

Comment: You demonstrated something else, Although it should work

Comment: Yeah, i did. I just did not want to have to create a plnkr for ALL of it, because that would have been really painful. But his appeared to show the same issue, so i went with it. BUT, it was not actually the solution for me. You know what i mean? lol